# Using SPServices to perform operation similar to the people picker - Possible?

Tags: people-picker, spservices

May I know if it is possible to use SPServices to perform similar operation like the people picker in InfoPath 2007?

In InfoPath form 2007, there is a field (called people-picker) that allow end-user to select people. I would like to know if I can use the SPServices to perform similar operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could certainly try to build something similar to the People Picker with SPServices, reading from the User Information List or User Profiles. But why would you want to when you have the People Picker, which works?